# Starting custom script after input device is connected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, udev

I have a Genius tablet and I need to remap some buttons on it when I connect it to the usb. The remmaping is done by this command:

```
xinput set-button-map 'Genius EasyPen M610X' 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 2
```

and I'm using udev to call a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 10
/usr/bin/xinput set-button-map 'Genius EasyPen M610X' 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 2
```

The script works fine, also the udev calls the script when the device is plugged in however the line with the xinput is not executed. Dmesg and syslog didn't say nothing about error, also using udevadm test device... is passing with no errors. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the output from `udevd --debug-trace --verbose` and 
 `strace -p pid_of_udevd -f -e trace=open,exec`

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, the output is too long however there were two lines which say about error with the script
`[212.579522] [2321] spawn_read: '/usr/local/bin/tablet.sh'(err) 'Unable to connect to X server'`
`[212.580112] [2321] spawn_wait: '/usr/local/bin/tablet.sh' [2326] exit with return code 1`

Comment: Are you using debian?

Comment: I'm using debian like distro Linux mint 13

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that the script is called with the `DISPLAY` environment variable unset. This variable tells X programs which display they are supposed to connected to. Try adding the following before calling `xinput`.

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

For example:

```
% export DISPLAY=:0
% xinput ...
```